# Producers, Consumers, and my cute Deadlock

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, pthreads

I'm working on a Producer Consumer (Multithreaded) problem and I'm encountering a deadlock. My question is how?

I have multiple producers creating n products, and putting them in a global queue. The producers must WAIT if there is no room in the queue.

My consumers are accessing the queue by using First Come First Serve. The consumer must WAIT if there is nothing in the queue. The consumer will consume PART of the product, and the product will only be removed from the queue when it has been totally consumed. The consumers will stop consuming when there are no more products to be consumed.

I get the deadlock when the first item is done being consumed. I am using a mutex to lock the queue, 2 condition variables to signal when an item is added or removed to the queue, and a semaphore to keep track of total items being consumed.

Any idea why it may be deadlocking?

Input: 2 (Producers) 3 (Consumers) 5 (Items to produce) 2 (Queue Size) 0 (N/A) 50 (Quantum) 1 (Seed)

Producer:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include "producerConsumer.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <sys/time.h>

void* producer(void* args)
{
    tProducer producer = *((tProducer*) args);
    tProduct products[producer.products];
    unsigned int queueMax = producer.queueMax;
    timeval time;
    std::string output;

    for(int i = 0; i < producer.products; i++)
    {
        //Create item
        products[i].productId = i;
        products[i].life = producer.lifeOfProduct;
        gettimeofday(&time, NULL);
        products[i].timestamp = time.tv_sec;

        //Lock and add to queue
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queueLock);

            //Queue is full and must wait
            if(queue.size() >= queueMax)
            {
                output = "Producer: " + std::to_string(producer.id) + " is waiting\n";
                std::cout << output;
                pthread_cond_wait(&removeSignal, &queueLock);
            }

            //Debug message
            output = "Producer: " + std::to_string(producer.id) + " is producing.\n";
            std::cout << output;

            //Add item to queue and signal
            queue.push(products[i]);
            pthread_cond_signal(&addSignal);
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueLock);
        //pthread_cond_signal(&addSignal);

        //Debug message
        output = "Producer: " + std::to_string(producer.id) + " just produced.\n";
        std::cout << output;
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Consumer:

```
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include "producerConsumer.h"
#include <iostream>
void* consumer(void* args)
{
    tConsumer consumer = *((tConsumer*) args);
    int id = consumer.id;
    int quantum = consumer.quantum;
    std::string output;

    while(true)
    {
        //Exit when nothing else is being created
        if(sem_trywait(&totalProductsLeft) < 0)
        {
            break;
        }

        //Subtract life from product, and remove from queue if done
        pthread_mutex_lock(&queueLock);

            //Wait until item is in queue
            if(queue.size() <= 0)
            {
                //Debug message
                output = "Consumer: " + std::to_string(id) + " is waiting.\n";
                std::cout << output;
                pthread_cond_wait(&addSignal, &queueLock);
            }

            //Debug message
            output = "Consumer: " + std::to_string(id) + " is ready.\n";
            std::cout << output;

            tProduct& product = queue.front();
            product.life -= quantum;

            //Item is done being consumed
            if(product.life <= 0)
            {
                //Debug message
                output = "Product: " + std::to_string(product.productId) + " is dead.\n";
                std::cout << output;

                //Remove a spot
                queue.pop();
                pthread_cond_signal(&removeSignal);
                sem_wait(&totalProductsLeft);
            }
            else
            {
                //Debug message
                output = "Product: " + std::to_string(product.life) + "hp is not done.\n";
                std::cout << output;
            }

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&queueLock);
    }

    //May need to broadcast
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

Main (Just to show how I initialize everything):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdio>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <semaphore.h>
#include "producerConsumer.h"

std::queue<tProduct> queue;
pthread_cond_t addSignal;
pthread_cond_t removeSignal;
sem_t totalProductsLeft;
pthread_mutex_t queueLock;

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    //Handle input
    const int NUM_INPUTS = 8;
    int numberProducers;
    int numberConsumers;
    int numberOfProducts;
    int queueSize;
    int scheduleType;
    int quantum;
    int seed;

    //Error check for input
    if(argc != NUM_INPUTS)
    {
        std::cout << "Invalid number of arguments.\n";
        return -1;
    }

    //Grab arguments
    numberProducers = atoi(argv[1]);
    numberConsumers = atoi(argv[2]);
    numberOfProducts = atoi(argv[3]);
    queueSize = atoi(argv[4]);
    scheduleType = atoi(argv[5]);
    quantum = atoi(argv[6]);
    seed = atoi(argv[7]);

    //Get rid of warnings for now
    std::cout << numberOfProducts << std::endl;
    std::cout << queueSize << std::endl;
    std::cout << quantum << std::endl;
    std::cout << seed << std::endl;
    std::cout << scheduleType << std::endl;

    //Create threads
    pthread_t producerThreads[numberProducers];
    pthread_t consumerThreads[numberConsumers];
    tProducer producerArgs[numberProducers];
    tConsumer consumerArgs[numberConsumers];

    //Initialize global
    pthread_mutex_init(&queueLock, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&addSignal, NULL);
    pthread_cond_init(&removeSignal, NULL);
    std::cout << "Total Items: " << (numberProducers * numberOfProducts) << std::endl;
    sem_init(&totalProductsLeft, 0, numberProducers * numberOfProducts);

    //Start threads
    srand(seed);
    for(int i = 0; i < numberProducers; i++)
    {
        producerArgs[i].id = i;
        producerArgs[i].products = numberOfProducts;
        producerArgs[i].lifeOfProduct = rand() % 1024;
        producerArgs[i].queueMax = queueSize;
        pthread_create(&(producerThreads[i]), 0, producer, &producerArgs[i]);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numberConsumers; i++)
    {
        consumerArgs[i].id = i;
        consumerArgs[i].quantum = quantum;
        pthread_create(&(consumerThreads[i]), 0, consumer, &consumerArgs[i]);
    }

    //Wait for threads to end
    for(int i = 0; i < numberProducers; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(producerThreads[i], NULL);
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < numberConsumers; i++)
    {
        pthread_join(consumerThreads[i], NULL);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This may not be your problem, but I should point out that due to _spurious wakeups_, `pthread_cond_wait()` is allowed to return without actually having been handled. That is why calls to `pthread_cond_wait()` should be wrapped in a loop that checks whether the invariant being waited for actually occured.

Comment: I figured it out the problem was with the sem_trywait(). It was decrementing when items weren't actually consumed. Great advice though.

Comment: You call `sem_trywait(&totalProductsLeft)` to see whether any products are left. This call will either succeed in decrementing the counter immediately or will return an error code if the count is 0. But then you call `sem_wait(&totalProductsLeft)` after `pthread_cond_signal(&removeSignal)` when the product life is over; This means that you're double-decrementing the semaphore (and potentially deadlocking on it when its count reaches 0) in the case that the product life is over.

Comment: Wups, looks like you got it yourself! Congratz.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up figuring it out. sem_trywait, in my consumer, is decrementing when items weren't done being consumed. The sem_wait inside my consumer is then blocking because there are no items left.